# Dissolving linestrings by uniqe value in field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, dissolve, linestring, aggregation

I want to dissolve a line geometry by a unique value in the field `"RoutenIDs"`. For example dissolve line 37 to 43 with value 27. Dissolve line 37-46 ... with value 1999 and so on. Is there a function or a plugin to do that in QGIS 3.20?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` with this expression to aggregate:

```
left ( "RoutenIDs", strpos( "RoutenIDs", ';')-1)
```

If you want the output to be an integer instead of a text (string), add `to_int()`.

[image]

Comment: I was up to post the identical answer ;-) but u were faster :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dissolve only for visual purposes (no actual geometries), you can use this expression with `Geometry generator` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-geometry-generator)):

```
buffer (collect_geometries (array_agg( $geometry,group_by:=routenids)),0)
```

Unfortunately, the option to create actual geometries using `Geometry by expression` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#geometry-by-expression)) does not work here because [aggregate functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#aggregates-functions) do not work well with `Geometry by expression` (see the [difference between both functions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).